# xpath nested ul list

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am banging my head against a wall here, its probably something simple that I am missing.

I have a HTML un-ordered list (ul) like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>Elm 1</li>
  <li>Elm 2 - with children
    <ul>
      <li>Nested Elm</li>
      <li>Another Elm</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using xpath (version 1 compatible with Scrapy), how would i get the text out of all the li elements including the nested one?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need xpath, use `response.xpath('//ul//li/text()').extract()`.
If you can use css, it is shorter: `response.css('ul li::text').extract()`

Answer (score 0):

Try with a simple xpath selector:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
selector = Selector(text="""
<ul>
  <li>Elm 1</li>
  <li>Elm 2 - with children
    <ul>
      <li>Nested Elm</li>
      <li>Another Elm</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>""")
print(selector.xpath('//li/text()').extract())
```

This outputs:

```
['Elm 1', 'Elm 2 - with children\n    ', 'Nested Elm', 'Another Elm', '\n  ']
```